# $.ajax + make success function parameterized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

A stupid question.

I am calling $.ajax function in many of my button clicks, text changed, drop down value changed etc. So I thought of making this function parameterized. Below is the code I was trying to use.

```
function ajaxCall(ajaxUrl, methodName) {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxUrl,
            success: methodName
            },
            dataType: "html"
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
```

In this the "methodName" should be the name of the method the control should go.
Or in short, when I use `ajaxCall('test.aspx','testMethod')`, the control should be transferred to

```
function testMethod(xmlResponse){
   alert ('Inside testMethod');
}
```

Comment: In what way did your code not work as expected?

Comment: so what is the real question or problem at hand?

Comment: I am expecting the control of the program to go to testMethod. But it is not going. If you have not noticed, the methodName is a string variable and the value is "testMethod".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In JavaScript you can use functions as variables, so just call `ajaxCall` with url and success handler.*

```
function testMethod (xmlResponse) {
   alert('Inside testMethod');
}

function ajaxCall (ajaxUrl, methodName) {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: methodName
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}

ajaxCall('test.aspx', testMethod);
```

Comment: Just answered. Thanks, anyways

Comment: You should accept his answer since it was a complete and working answer!

Comment: @SperanskyDanil, Anthony I accepted your answer as answer. But I could not accept your answer because it was giving me a "Wait for 2 mins to accept this answer". Also, I did not answer the above stuff by looking at your response. I did search in the web and found it out some where. I guess you were thinking that I was taking the credit from you.